# Event of receiving data in angular child component from parent using Input()

Tags: angular, components, parent-child

I am developing one application on **Angular 7**. Faced issue finding the proper **event when data is received in child component from the parent component**. I am using **@Input()** to share data from parent to child. Changed data is populated in HTML but not able to get in TS file to make modification and other changes when new data is received.

Parent component is doing an ajax call and sharing the response to child component.  I have tried onInit, onChange and afterViewInit events in child component. I do not want to use behavior subject (**rxjs**).

Comment: Can you show a code snippet?

Comment: You can use `ngOnChanges` to achieve that... If you have some _object_ or _array_ as an `@Input` then you will have to create a new object/array when setting a value for that input...

Comment: @miselking, You mean if I assign new field in the same object it will not reflect on ngOnChnages?

Comment: If you just assign value to a field inside an _object_ that will _not_ be reflected in `ngOnChanges`. What you should do is instantiate the object again (something like `someObj = { field1: ..., field2: ... }`).